# PHP Directory Structure: Shifting from Linux Hosting to Windows Hosting

Tags: php, windows, directory, security

I have using a a specific directory Structure for all my PHP applications i.e to keep my class and config files in folder above the public_html folder. And this structure , is very well suggested by many experienced PHP programs as it increases the security of ones application. This is working just fine for me.

But recently I shifted to a Windows Hosting Service just to get additional .net support for my development environment. Now , **The problem is don't have the permission to create any folder above the httdocs folder. Then , how do I maintain to keep my class and config files outside the folder which is accessible from the web.**

I am sure many of you have came across the same and have solved the problem before. Kindly help me figure this out.

Comment: Switch to a new service where you can control directory permissions.

Comment: I already bought this service for a year. :(

Comment: If you can't create a folder outside of htdocs then you obviously can't put the files outside of htdocs. You could put them within your webroot and use an htaccess file to `deny from all` so the web server won't access the folder. The files will still be available from within php, but not directly accessible through apache.

Comment: if the service supports it place all of your code in a directory under the doc root that excluded from being served.  This article may help http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments

Comment: Well, then I would contact the service to see what they can do about giving you another directory outside of the web root that you can modify. I would hope any decent service should be able to do this for you.  Any web app of reasonable complexity should be able to read/write to at least some location outside of web root.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get PHP to work on a Windows host has never worked out very well, in my experience.  PHP seems to get implemented poorly or at least differently in Windows and that can cause some real headaches.
I would not advise trying to do PHP in Windows, even if you have already paid for the hosting.